# Array Formula with AverageIF of a row

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a formula in a Google Sheet that is averaging the values in a row...

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:L2,"<>0")
```

Simple, right?

However, I cannot figure out how to get the `ARRAYFORMULA` to work for this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGEIF(A2:L,"<>0")
```

That formula only averages all of the cells in the range, instead of returning the average for each row. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

you were close. try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:L),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A),
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")", ))&"")), 
 "select Col2"))
```

then to add `<>0` you need:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:L),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A),
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")", ))&
 "where "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 "not Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&"=0", ))&"")), 
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I get a Formula parse error.I've put a workaround by summing in one column, counting the non-zero cells, and the computing the average that way.  This is taking 3 columns versus 1, but it works.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?