# Google Sheets Column function to get Average of all the columns in a range to the right using current row

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm not sure why I can't find examples of this.
But I want my column E to have an average of all the columns to the right. In single example it's:
=AVERAGE(F2:O2)

Now I try to do this for the whole column:
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(E:E)=1,"Aggregate",AVERAGE(F:O)))

The problem is it doesn't do it per row, it just does the whole array. Maybe i don't want to use ArrayFormula

I should also put a IF(ISBLANK(F (Row())), "" So I don't calculate blank rows.

How do I put dynamic row on this?

Comment: This is almost working:
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(E:E)=1,"Aggregate",AVERAGE(INDIRECT(CONCAT("F", ROW())):INDIRECT(CONCAT("P", ROW())))))

But the 2nd indirect always give me div by 0 error

Comment: Hello, this post have an answer here! Try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219049

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array Formula with AverageIF of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218199/array-formula-with-averageif-of-a-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F2:O), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, 
 IF(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F2:O),,99^99)))<>"", 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(F2:F)-ROW(F2)+1&")", ))&"")),
 "select Col2"))
```

[image: 0]